# How can I convert while loop to for loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop

I am having problems, converting while loop to for loop. How will this look in a for loop format, any help would be really appreciated. the actual file is stored on github > [github link](https://github.com/tmamedbekov/JSON_Generator/blob/master/in-out.html)

```
          //language
          while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
              if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
                  regex.lastIndex++;
              }
              m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
                  output = output+`{\n"Language": "${match}"\n`;
              });
          }
```

Comment: The code isn't a good match for a `for` statement. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: the middle statement in a for loop is the same as a while loop. `for(;(m = regex.exec(str)) !== null;){...}`

Comment: `for loop` are good when you know the number of `iteration` or when you've two polarity. Here you can't know when the test in you're `while` is good so you can't change the `loop`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall the standard form of the `while` loop:

```
while (test) {
    body;
}
```

And the standard form of the `for` loop:

```
for (initialization; test; update) {
    body;
}
```

It's *possible* to change your `while` to a `for`, but it doesn't make much sense to:

```
for (m = regex.exec(str); m !== null ; m = regex.exec(str)) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        output = output + `{\n"Language": "${match}"\n`;
    });
}
```

Note that the initialization and the update are the same; duplicated code.

Alternately:

```
for ( ; (m = regex.exec(str)) !== null ; ) {
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        output = output + `{\n"Language": "${match}"\n`;
    });
}
```

Note that both the initialization and the update are both blank.

Comment: The problem is that I have many while loops in my code, and I want to convert all the while loops into 1 for loop. So the story behind it, is: I drop the log file in the first field, slick start, it runs through all the lines, and creates a formatted JSON output. At the moment it creates an output that runs each RegEx and it is not formatted the proper way. I need it to run all the RegEx rules, on each line, and then go to the next line of the "log file". Thats why I am thinking I need to have a for loop.

Comment: @tonym You need to revise your question to show what you're really trying to accomplish. Show a few of the `while` loops, and explain what the result should be of all of them.